# How to fix Flutter Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm developing a web app using Flutter Web and RESTful API for backend.
So, I'm trying the fetch the data from the api, serialize it by using Flutter Models, then return the result.

The Problem is, I'm getting this result

```
Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'
```

How to fix this ?

Here's my flutter codes:

**models**

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final medicalRecordsModel = medicalRecordsModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

class MedicalRecordsModel {
  MedicalRecordsModel({
    this.id,
    this.category,
    this.fileName,
    this.dateTimestamp,
    this.description,
    this.upload,
    this.patientName,
    this.age,
    this.address,
    this.userId,
    this.patientId,
    this.isActive,
  });

  final String id;
  final String category;
  final String fileName;
  final String dateTimestamp;
  final String description;
  final String upload;
  final String patientName;
  final String age;
  final String address;
  final dynamic userId;
  final int patientId;
  final bool isActive;

  factory MedicalRecordsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MedicalRecordsModel(
      id: json["id"],
      category: json["category"],
      fileName: json["fileName"],
      dateTimestamp: json["dateTimestamp"],
      description: json["description"],
      upload: json["upload"],
      patientName: json["patientName"],
      age: json["age"],
      address: json["address"],
      userId: json["userId"],
      patientId: json["patientId"],
      isActive: json["isActive"],
    );
  }
}
```

**API Connection**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:app/src/constants/medical_records.dart';
import 'package:app/src/models/medical_records/medical_records.dart';
import 'package:app/src/pages/Medical-Records/medical_record.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class MedicalRecordsManager {
  var client = http.Client();
  var url = ConstantMedicalRecords.medical_records_api;

  Future<MedicalRecordsModel> getRecords() async {
    var url = ConstantMedicalRecords.medical_records_api;
    log('$url');
    try {
      final response = await client.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return MedicalRecordsModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
        // print(recordsModel);
      }
    } catch (Exception) {
      print(Exception);
      print("Error occured");
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the JSON data I want to get

```
 {
        "id": "103",
        "category": "DOCUMENT",
        "fileName": "Check Up",
        "dateTimestamp": "2021-02-1012:59:46",
        "description": "string",
        "upload": "String",
        "patientName": "1",
        "age": "25",
        "address": "Earth",
        "userId": null,
        "patientId": 12,
        "isActive": true
    }
```

Please help me with this one.

Comment: are you sure you are only returning one MedicalRecordsManager?... based on the method naming getRecords().. should it be Future<List<MedicalRecordsManager >>?.. try printing out the json response and debug it well

Comment: @Reign I want to return more than  data

Comment: You can make this process much easier. Please look at this answer. Using only one function call, you get the finished result. This method has been tested and covered in tests. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66632608/1737201

Comment: Do none of these answers work?

Answer (score 9):

you can do it like that

```
MedicalRecordsModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

Answer (score 6):

change the `getRecord` as follows

```
Future<MedicalRecordsModel> getRecords() async {
    var url = ConstantMedicalRecords.medical_records_api;
    log('$url');
    try {
      final response = await client.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return MedicalRecordsModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[0]);
        // print(recordsModel);
      }
    } catch (Exception) {
      print(Exception);
      print("Error occured");
    }
  }
```

I think `jsonDecode` gives list of Maps therefore your json map is the first element of that list.

Comment: thanks bro json[0] it's help me to get ride from this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This code wiil work as you expected:

```dart
import 'package:json_helpers/json_helpers.dart';

void main() {
  // responseBody is the same response.body

  // When response is a list of objects
  final list = responseBody1.jsonList((e) => MedicalRecordsModel.fromJson(e));
  var obj = list[0];
  print(obj.category);
  print(obj.fileName);

  // When response is an object
  obj = responseBody2.json((e) => MedicalRecordsModel.fromJson(e));
  print(obj.category);
  print(obj.fileName);
}

final responseBody1 = '''
[
   {
      "id":"103",
      "category":"DOCUMENT",
      "fileName":"Check Up",
      "dateTimestamp":"2021-02-1012:59:46",
      "description":"string",
      "upload":"String",
      "patientName":"1",
      "age":"25",
      "address":"Earth",
      "userId":null,
      "patientId":12,
      "isActive":true
   }
]''';

final responseBody2 = '''
{
   "id":"103",
   "category":"DOCUMENT",
   "fileName":"Check Up",
   "dateTimestamp":"2021-02-1012:59:46",
   "description":"string",
   "upload":"String",
   "patientName":"1",
   "age":"25",
   "address":"Earth",
   "userId":null,
   "patientId":12,
   "isActive":true
}''';

class MedicalRecordsModel {
  final String id;

  final String category;
  final String fileName;
  final String dateTimestamp;
  final String description;
  final String upload;
  final String patientName;
  final String age;
  final String address;
  final dynamic userId;
  final int patientId;
  final bool isActive;
  MedicalRecordsModel({
    this.id,
    this.category,
    this.fileName,
    this.dateTimestamp,
    this.description,
    this.upload,
    this.patientName,
    this.age,
    this.address,
    this.userId,
    this.patientId,
    this.isActive,
  });

  factory MedicalRecordsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return MedicalRecordsModel(
      id: json['id'] as String,
      category: json['category'] as String,
      fileName: json['fileName'] as String,
      dateTimestamp: json['dateTimestamp'] as String,
      description: json['description'] as String,
      upload: json['upload'] as String,
      patientName: json['patientName'] as String,
      age: json['age'] as String,
      address: json['address'] as String,
      userId: json['userId'] as String,
      patientId: json['patientId'] as int,
      isActive: json['isActive'] as bool,
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

```
DOCUMENT
Check Up
DOCUMENT
Check Up
```

That is, when response is a list of objects:

```dart
final list = response.body.jsonList((e) => MedicalRecordsModel.fromJson(e));
```

When response is an object:

```dart
final object = response.body.json((e) => MedicalRecordsModel.fromJson(e));
```

If you don't know what the result is, then you can try both methods.

```
response.body.json((e) => Model.fromJson(e));
response.body.jsonList((e) => Model.fromJson(e));
```

If you have already decoded a JSON string and want to convert the result (or part of it), you can use the following methods:

If the type of the decoded `value` is `Map`:

```dart
final object = value.json((e) => Model.fromJson(e));
```

If the type of the decoded `value` is `List`:

```dart
final objects = value.json((e) => Model.fromJson(e));
```

Comment: Where are you getting that response.body.Json and response.body.jsonList function from?

Answer (score 2):

Every response is sended and received as text, which can be converted to the
Map Format with the dart inbuilt core library `import 'dart:convert';`.

So the response from the request can be treated like this.

```
final res = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),  body: json.encode({
          'userId': uid,
          'email': email,
        }),
        head body: json.encode({
          'userId': uid,
          'email': email,
        }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'token64': token});
```

here `json.encode()` is used to convert to String from Map.

now res variable contain the response which is also a string which can be convert to the Map with `json.decode()` like this.

```
final data = json.decode(res);
```

when working with the data sometimes we occur errors like Map is not a type of `Map<String, String>` etc.

Which can be solved by type casting the res, like this.

```
Map<String, String> notification = Map<String, String>.from(data['notification']);
```

I see these type casting method used in the The boring Flutter Development show in Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

[image: my approach to the problem]

I faced the same kind of problem after I built an API and tried consuming it in flutter. I first extracted the data and check if the extracted data is null. When the condition is false, I made a list  **loadStudents** that will hold the data after the loop. This is what worked out for me after a ton of stress looking for solutions online.